# PHP multiple if statements only doing last statement

Tags: php, mysql

I know similar questions have been asked a lot, and I have searched through and am unable to find an answer that fixes the problem I am having.

I have a form with multiple textareas that updates a mysql entry, and I would like PHP to make sure there is something in the textarea before updating the entry.  This works when I only have one entry being updated, but when I do more than one at a time only the last one is updated.  I tried using else if, and in that case only the first one is updated.  How can I make it update all entries where text has been entered?

In my code the form input name matches the column name.

```
$value = $_POST['titleLeft'];
$value2 = $_POST['textLeft'];
$value3 = $_POST['imgName'];
$value4 = $_POST['titleRight'];
$value5 = $_POST['textRight'];

if (strlen($value) > 0){
    $sql = "UPDATE classesSpecial SET titleLeft = '$value' WHERE id = '1'";
}

if (strlen($value2) > 0){
    $sql = "UPDATE classesSpecial SET textLeft = '$value2' WHERE id = '1'";
}

if (strlen($value3) > 0){
$sql = "UPDATE classesSpecial SET imgName = '$value3' WHERE id = '1'";
}

if (strlen($value4) > 0){
    $sql = "UPDATE classesSpecial SET titleRight = '$value4' WHERE id = '1'";
}

if (strlen($value5) > 0){
    $sql = "UPDATE classesSpecial SET textRight = '$value5' WHERE id = '1'";
}
```

Comment: You're not executing the query. I presume you're doing that after, but you're overwriting `$sql` each time a condition is evaluted true

Comment: Not a direct answer, but please have a read on [sql injections](http://php.net/manual/fr/security.database.sql-injection.php) and [how to prevent them](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered, I did not expect to get this done until the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you keep on overwriting `$sql`. One solution would be to do this for each post request:

```
if((strlen($value) > 0) {
  $sql[] = "UPDATE classesSpecial SET titleLeft = '$value' WHERE id = 1";
}
```

`$sql[]` means you're adding values to an array, which you can later use to process all requests. Then, at the end of your script, you'll do this for executing your SQL:

```
foreach($sql as $query) {
  mysqli_query($db, $query)or die(mysqli_error($db));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same variable `$sql` everytime,

```
$value = $_POST['titleLeft'];
$value2 = $_POST['textLeft'];
$value3 = $_POST['imgName'];
$value4 = $_POST['titleRight'];
$value5 = $_POST['textRight'];

if (strlen($value) > 0){
    $sql1 = "UPDATE classesSpecial SET titleLeft = '$value' WHERE id = '1'";
}

if (strlen($value2) > 0){
    $sql2 = "UPDATE classesSpecial SET textLeft = '$value2' WHERE id = '1'";
}

if (strlen($value3) > 0){
$sql3 = "UPDATE classesSpecial SET imgName = '$value3' WHERE id = '1'";
}

if (strlen($value4) > 0){
    $sql4 = "UPDATE classesSpecial SET titleRight = '$value4' WHERE id = '1'";
}

if (strlen($value5) > 0){
    $sql5 = "UPDATE classesSpecial SET textRight = '$value5' WHERE id = '1'";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're overwriting the sql query with each if.
you should also execute the command in the if statement.